# Refesh Website when maximized and restore button is pressed jquery

Tags: jquery, window-resize

I want to reload a website when a user shrinks the browser window. I have gotten that to work, but when you press the **maximize** button after you have shrinked the browser window in size, it doesn't refresh back to normal, it stays in the mobile view.

I have found a code that sort of works but not 100%.
I would really appreciate if someone here could help me. I am really new to javascript/jQuery. Down below is the jQuery code I feel it is not the best looking but it sort of works.

```js
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
  var windowSize = $(window).width(); // Could've done $(this).width()
  //Smartphones, Portrait iPhone, Portrait 480x320 Phones (Android)
  if (windowSize < 320) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

    //Smartphones, Android Phones, Landscape iPhone
  } else if (windowSize < 480) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  }
  //Portrait Tablets, Portrait iPad, E-readers (Nook/Kindle), Landscape 800x480 Phones (Android)
  else if (windowSize < 600) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  } else if (windowSize < 690) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  }
  //Tablet, Landscape iPad, Lo-res Laptops and Desktops
  else if (windowSize < 801) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  } else if (windowSize < 995) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  }
  //Big Landscape Tablets, Laptops, and Desktops 
  else if (windowSize < 1025) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  }
  //Hi-res Laptops and Desktops 
  else if (windowSize < 1281) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  } else if (windowSize < 1440) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 200);
    });

  } else if (windowSize > 1440) {
    //Refresh page on browser resize
    $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
      $('body').prepend('<div>' + $(window).width() + '</div>');
      if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
      window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
      }, 10);
    });

  } else {
    $('html').css('color', 'black');
  }
});
```

Comment: Use Media Queries Rather than Window Width

Comment: OK, I have changed some of the code to this now if ($('.toggle-menu').width() == 320 )

Answer (score 0):

So I have got most of it to work now. But I it keeps on updating when I am lets say 1050px. Does anyone know if it is possible for it to just update when the exact resolution is matched?. I tought I have done that with the === but No.

jQuery:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(event) {
     var windowSize = $(window).width(); // Could've done $(this).width()
     if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 1599) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 1300) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 820) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 821) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 1024) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 900) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 768) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     } else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 769) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     }
       else if ($('.toggle-menu').width() === 1050) {
      //Refresh page on browser resize
      $(window).bind('resize', function(e) {
       if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
       window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
        this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
       }, 1000);
      });
     }
    });
//Update the website when you press the maximize button
$(window).resize( function(e) {
   if (window.RT) clearTimeout(window.RT);
   window.RT = setTimeout(function() {
      this.location.reload(false); /* False to get page from cache */
   }, 10);
});
```